# What is the way of applying operations between rows in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, rolling-computation

I have a sales table and I would like to compute percentage of increase in sales between 2 years. I could create the table which includes the sales happed in  2 years but I couldn't find a way to make operations on them. I would like to apply ((sales in 2018)- (sales in 2017))* 100 / (sales in 2017) operation. Is there any way for applying this operation?
[sales table for years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQQqp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of rolling calculations, tableau offers `table calculations`.  I have prepared a similar cross-tab like yours, and follow like the GIF below

[image]

Basically you have have to apply a **table calculation** on aggregated measure i.e. `sum(sales)` here by right clicking it and selecting `% difference`.

Comment: thank you :) Is there any way to show only one year row ( ex: 2018) in the table with the calculated result by using the previous year (2017)?

Comment: I'll check and revert. Please feel free to accept and Upvote as usually desired on SO

Comment: Check [this]("Hiding Only the Blank Column when Using Difference Table Calculation | Tableau Software" https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/hiding-blank-column-table-difference-calc)